# How does Dymola choose the iteration variables during nonlinear system initialization process?

Tags: modelica, dymola

Assuming I have a very complicated thermal-fluid model built with Dymola. During the initialization process, how would dymola choose the iteration variables for the nonlinear solver? Is there a standard for this issue in dymola? I wanna make this clear, cause sometimes if the start values of the iteration variables are too far away from the right solution, there would be a divergence issue during the initialization process. I think if I could know the choice of iteration variables,  I could make sure their values are appropriate instead of checking all the start values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this information is not available to the public. At least I could not find anything in the user manuals. Therefore, you have only limited options.

What you can do is:

- List your current iteration variables
- Try to influence the selection
- Get information on performed iterations

#### List iteration variables

You can list your current iteration variables by activating the flag

```
Advanced.LogNonLinearIterationVariables = true;
```

The iteration variables will be listed in the `Translation` tab as info message `Variables appearing in the nonlinear systems of equations`:

[image: screenshot of iteration variables]

#### Influence selected variables

You can influence (but not control) the variables selected for iteration by setting start values. Take this code for example:

```
model MyNonLinear
  Real x;
  Real y;
  Real z(start=-1);
equation 
  0 = y - z;
  x = (y + z)^2;
  x = (y + z) + time;
end MyNonLinear;
```

If you translate it with the above flag active, Dymola will give this information in the translation tab of the message window:

> Iteration variables:
>   y

When you additionally set a start value for x, (e.g. `start=1`) x becomes the iteration variable in this case.

#### Information on performed iterations

To get more information on the performed iterations, activate the `Nonlinear solver diagnostics` flags in the `Debug` tab of the `Simulation Setup`:

[image: Nonlinear solver flags]

Dymola will then display additional information in the simulation log. Note that some of these flags can generate a log of output.

Comment: I built a model of a power plant, the translation passed, but because of the start values were not good enough, the initialization iteration ended with a divergence, so I checked all the iteration variables, they were all in the appropriate range.  Since there are hundreds of variables in the model, I can’t change the values one by one, so How could I find that which  iteration variables I should modify to ensure the convergence?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible via a very lightly documented feature. See the 2019 FD01 release highlights for some limited info: https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS/CATIA/DYMOLA/PDF/Dymola-2019FD01-highlights.pdf

Specifically:[image]